# Will a C+ on one major core class greatly affect CS masters admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

I am interested in applying to some MS Computer Science programs in the US and my official GPA is 3.95. I went to a T20 private university in the US for undergrad, but in my freshman year I had a terrible professor for data structures + a heavy workload, and I was also generally just figuring out college at that time as an international student. The consequence was that I received a passing C+ on data structures. But from sophomore year to graduation, I have managed to get almost all A's on all my classes and maintained a good GPA in the end.

I am really scared that because I got a really terrible grade for one of the important CS fundamental classes, this will greatly impact my grad school applications. I understand that there is nothing I can do now except just try to strengthen other parts of my application. I did do a lot of internship and project work outside of school. Just hoping to get some insights from everyone here. Thank you!

Comment: I'd say you are a near lock to get into someplace, presuming you apply to a range of schools. But you have to apply to a range of schools, and enough of them. Just a numbers game at some level.

Comment: Yeah, C++ would be better...

Comment: @JonCuster I see. Thanks! Will definitely apply wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unlikely that it would be a large factor, especially for a first-year course. But the competition can be tough in top rated schools.

In the US people tend to take a broad view of candidates and few things are disqualifying. In particular, letters of recommendation are very important.

It is what it is, however. But you seem to have recovered from the experience with a good GPA. Don't lose sleep over it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great advice :)